# insert-button: all action point to last path

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following elisp code:

```
(defun my-process-file (fPath)
  "Process the file at FPATH …"
  (let (myBuffer p1 p2 (ii 0) searchStr)
    (when
        (and (not (string-match "/xx" fPath)) ) ; exclude some dir

      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents fPath nil nil nil t)

        (setq searchStr "planos" ) ; search string here

        (goto-char 1)
        (while (search-forward searchStr nil t)
          (setq ii (1+ ii))
          (setq number-line (what-line))
          )

        (if (not (= ii 0))
            (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*my occur output*")
              (setq file-path fPath)
              (insert-button (concat file-path "\n") 'action (lambda (x) (find-file (concat file-path)))))
           )))))
```

The my-process-file is call for each file on directory, and search files than match with 'planos' (or other string). All works fine, but on results, all action on "insert-button" point to the last value at 'fPaht'.

I do not know if I made ​​myself clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind all buttons to the lambda expression `(lambda (x) (find-file (concat file-path)))))`.  The effect is that when the are executed, they will look up the value of the variable `file-path`, which refers to the last file read.

You will need to attach the current value of `file-path` to the expression or to the button, somehow. One way to do this is to replace the variable with the value when you create the lambda expression. You can do this with plain old lisp using something like `(list 'lambda '(x) (list 'file-file (concat file-path)))`. Or you can use the backtick syntax `` `(lambda (x) (find-file ,(concat file-path))) ``.

Comment: @elf A more elegant solution would be to simply attach the file path to the button itself, by storing it in a button property, whose value you can then obtain in the handler.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: @lunaryorn, I agree, I would recommend your solution over mine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply attach the path of the file to the button, and read it in the handler:

```
(insert-button (concat file-path "\n")
               'my-file-path file-path
               'action (lambda (btn)
                         (find-file (button-get btn 'my-file-path))))
```

`my-file-path` is simply the name of the property where the file path is stored.  You may use whatever name you like, but you should pick a distinctive name to avoid a conflict with the [standard button properties](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Button-Properties.html#Button-Properties).

You could then even replace the `lambda` with a generic function:

```
(defun my-button-action (button)
  (find-file (button-get button 'my-file-path)))

(insert-button (concat file-path "\n")
               'my-file-path file-path
               'action #'my-button-action)
```